1950s B & W thriller from England about a boy who witnesses a murder and then gets chased by the heavy/large murderer
I am trying to find the name of an old movie I saw about 50 years ago on TV.  Black and White, I believe made in England but not 100% sure.  Seems made around 1950s.
Plot as best as I can recall is about a little boy about 10 years old who witnesses a crime (murder I think) and towards the end of the film he is chased by the killer through what I think is a train station, or subway with tunnels, and a large hole in the floor, etc.  The murderer who chased him looked heavy and large.
It scared me a great deal when I was little and I have not been able to find it since.  It is not "The Window". I have asked many places, IMDB and TCM were of no help.

A vote to close in less than 22 minutes with no explanation?

Hi, I am new to this website, and really have lloked for years for the name of this movie, and so I do not understand why my request for help has a minus mark within an hour of my posting it?  This is all the information I can recall after 50 years.  As far as my doing more research, I am out of places to look, that is why I came here as I thought the folks here were knowledgeable and could help me.  This is an honest plea for help.  What's with the negative vibes?  Bee

@MMM You have already provided more details than many bad "identify this" questions here. Normally we would like to see more detail, but please don't be discouraged, you are just seeing the knock-on effect of too many bad questions by others.

Perhaps you are thinking of The Yellow Balloon.
From the Wikipedia plot summary: 

"Len blackmails Frankie into stealing money from his parents (Kenneth
  More and Kathleen Ryan) to help fund Len's escape and then uses the
  boy as a decoy in a pub robbery that goes horribly wrong when Len
  murders the pub owner. Realising that Frankie is the only witness to
  his crime, Len knows he must kill the boy, too. This develops into a
  terrifying hide-and-seek chase through a bomb-damaged, abandoned and
  highly-perilous London Underground station, with Len hot on the heels
  of Frankie, who is desperately trying to escape with his life."


Thank you. I think this sounds very much like the film I am seeking.  The killer in my mind looked very different than the man in this film, but that may be a clouded memory from 50 years ago.   The little boy in The Yellow Balloon wears a very similar suit to the boy in the film I saw, and looks similar with blond hair, so this just may be it.  Now I have to find a way to view this film.  I thought it interesting that the film was rated "X" when it first came out, due to the  ending being considered too scary for children to see. So no wonder I was so frightened when I saw it as a child!

This film when you described it reminded me of a dvd I rented from the library a few years back. It was b&w and I'd been trying to remember the name of it when I ran across your post - it was British-made, 1963 about a boy who witnessed a murder by the 'butler' (not as cheesey as it sounds, but a really dark psychodrama) It was called The Servant - it sounded alot like you described...Hope this helps!
...PS, missed the post about The Yellow Balloon and your reply - I remember that one too - totally different from The Servant, but another good one if you like that genre.. Cheers!

You might want to highlight the title, otherwise it's hard to find it in the text and readers might misunderstand you answer as a comment
